# nopCommerce paypal PDTHandler redirect url problem

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, payment, nopcommerce

I am working on paypal payment part to integrate in my nopCommerce 4.5+ version project. I have installed Paypal Standard in my local plugin and also configure the redirect url in pyapal merchant account. When, I order and pay the product via Paypal sandbox account, it does the transaction. After the transaction, paypal page shows the confirmation with button "Back to the seller page". When I click this button, it returns error 400 and does not redirect to my website. Is it a nopcommerce Paypal plugin problem or Paypal issue?

Comment: Can you share the controller name, action name (for pdthandler), and Url that uses for redirection from paypal?